# PHP POST - no value in array when passing from php file to another

Tags: php, sql, arrays, post

I have a table of records pulled from SQL DB.
The admin can filter it, for example, only show Orders This Year, or Buy Orders Only etc.

I need to be able to export only filtered records into an excel file.
I have a Main.php that shows the records, and a export.php that exports and download the file.

My idea of doing this is whatever that is filtered, I grab all the OrderID, store in an array, and pass them over to export.php using POST method to print out.

My issue is with the passing value over. I keep getting an empty array!

I don't know if it has something to do with sequence of order. Because my EXPORT button is on top of the recrods, my array technically has no value? However for presentation purpose, I need the EXPORT button to be above the records.

Main.php

```
<?php
$filtered_OID = array();
?>

<form method="post" action="export.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="exportf" value="<?php echo serialize($filtered_OID); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="send" value="Export Filtered" />
</form>


<?php
...very long php code to query sql and show records...

array_push($filtered_OID, $row2[orderid]);

...very long php code to query sql and show records...
?>
```

export.php

```
if(isset($_POST["exportf"]))
{
    //echo unserialize($_POST["exportf"]);
    print_r($_POST["exportf"]);
    //print_r(unserialize($_POST["exportf"]));
    //var_dump($_POST["exportf"]);
}
```

Result from export.php

```
a:0:{}
```

Thank you

Comment: $filtered_OID is null at your code. Just rearrange it.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I need the Export Button to be above the Table for presentation purpose. Otherwise rearranging will put the Button at the very bottom of the table...

Comment: Don't echo anything until you've calculated everything.  Store all pending output in strings  instead.  Then just output  the strings in the order you want,  including all the calculated values you need

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$filtered_OID = array();
?>

<?php
    ...very long php code to query sql and show records...
    
    array_push($filtered_OID, $row2[orderid]);
    
    ...very long php code to query sql and show records...
    ?>

<form method="post" action="export.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="exportf" value="<?php echo serialize($filtered_OID); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="send" value="Export Filtered" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, not the solution I'm looking for. Doing this will put the Button below the Table, which is not what I want.

Comment: why? use jquery to populate result in  div.